# Java.lang.NullPointerException al querer cargar jtable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

soy nuevo aki  me surgio un problema, trataré de ser claro...
Tengo una clase personal.java la cual tiene los atributos del personal, los atributos están encapsulados y tienen sus métodos setter&getter, la clase tiene el constructor también.

Luego tengo un formulario(jInternalFrame) frm_personal el cual contiene un jpanel y dentro de este tengo una jtable.

```
Private DefaultTableModel miTabla;

Private Datos misDatos;

public void setDatos(Datos misDatos){
  this.misDatos = misDatos;
}
//todo el código correspondiente al constructor del //formulario

private void formInternalFrameOpened(..........){
  llenarTabla();
}

public void llenarTabla(){
 try{
  String títulos[] = {"ID", "Nombres"};
  String registro = new String[2];
  miTabla = new DefaultTableModel(null, registro);

  ResultSet rs= misDatos.getPersonal();
  while(es.next()){
     registro[0] = ""+rs.getInt("ID");
     registro[1] = rs.getString("nombres");
     miTabla.addRow(registro);
  }
  tblTabla.setModel(miTabla);
}catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.show........
}
}

X último una clase datos.java la cual contiene la consulta a la base de datos(mysql).

 public ResultSet getPersonal(){
  try{
    String sql= "SELECT * FROM personal";
    PreparedStatement pst= cn.prepareStatement(sql);
    return pst.executeQuery(sql);
   }catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.show........
     return null;
   }
}
```

Bien, quiero obtener los valores de la BD y ponerlo en la tabla y ahí me larga Java.lang.nullpointerexception cuando ejecuta el programa.
Espero se entienda los puntos suspensivos tienen código
Cuando ejecuto y llamo al form personal sale el java.lang.nullpointerexception y cdo acepto la ventana del error recién abre el form pero la tabla no carga
Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Ya leí ese post y no soluciona mi problema... antes de formular la pregunta leí e investigue mucho aquí y en la web... y ya e visto si cree y inicialize los obj con New

Comment: Algo para añadir, al ser principiante nose usarlo pero intente con el debug, el programa se ejecuta y cuando llega a la línea del ResultSet rs= misDatos.getPersonal(); ....Salta al catch(excepción e){}

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema... el inconveniente era que cuando llamo al formulario

frm_personal miPersonal = new frm_personal();
No le pase los valores del objeto Datos. O sea ..

mi personal.setDatos(misDatos);

Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Por si te hace ilusión puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Por tanto este post [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cuál-es-la-solución-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) si que solucionaba tu problema

Comment: Se podría decir que si... ya que estaba trayendo valor null

Comment: Se podría decir que si... ya que estaba trayendo valor null

Comment: Para votar la respuesta debo ir al otro post?